# How would a world where the air is poisonous impact weapons development?

Tags: warfare, technological-development

Bulkheads and windows would be pressurized compared to the outside, so armor piercing rounds and high caliber weapons would be detrimental to both sides. Flamethrowers are out (unless you're crazy... and some people are). But at the same time, people still need killin'. I tried (and failed) to find any information about weapons aboard submarines or spacecraft, which is the style of living I envision these people having.

For reference: in this world biological warfare has rendered the outside dangerous, so air filters on everyone is just a fact of daily life. Are there substances that easily bypass conventional filtration systems? Are there records of weapons designed to kill/incapacitate people in biohazard gear, even circa WWI?

Comment: How about [Are there any weapons in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/4019/415) on [space.se]? You may also be interested in [Realistic space battle, how it could looke like? No hollywood version or videogames like](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/5150/415). I found both literally by going to our sister site [space.se] and typing `weapons` into the search box.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit?  Biological warfare != poison.  Filtration systems can be tuned to block different things.  An N95 respirator that will stop most biological pathogens (bacteria & viruses) will not do a thing to stop, say, cyanide or chlorine gases.

Comment: On subs I'm pretty sure they use normal handguns because a) they're required very rarely and b) the bullets are unlikely to pierce the hull.

Comment: On subs and ships using shotguns is favored because you can bounce the rounds around and they can't penetrate the hull.

Answer (score 1):

Given the lethality outside I figure puncturing the 'hull' would be something nobody wants. So that leaves anything capable of penetrating body armor out really. Beanbags, tasers and buckshot are great though.

As for weapons aboard spacecraft. There aren't really that many as we're trying to minimize the arming of space. The Soviets however worked on a [laser pistol](http://www.thefirearmblog.com/blog/2013/10/08/soviet-laser-pistol/). Though this wasn't in any way a fearsome weapon. It main purpose was blinding sensors and if neccesary burning a hole in a Astronaut's suit. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the focus would be on low pentetrating ordnance for indoor combat, and high penetrating ordance for exterior combat. Mech suits or pressurised/armoured suits for use outside will have been created (because people need to breathe), so I would suggest a 12.7 - 20mm machine gun or chain gun firing AP rounds for use outside, with a high rate of fire and great penetration, whilst saving some weight. Anti armour missiles are also great, like wire guided TOWs or a Javelin.

Now I don't have any sources as such, and will find them if I have the time, but ceramic based rounds have been developed for fighting inside aircraft (for special forces/hostage rescue etc.). These rounds shatter when hitting anything, so are designed to not penetrate the skin of the plane (bad things will happen if they did). These seem to fit the requirement for combat inside. I believe the rounds were chambered in 9mm for the MP5, a great gun for close quarter action.

Comment: You've covered two cases nicely. Consider that there may be a couple of other cases, including 1) making an enemy's base uninhabitable, in which case explosives would be a good plan, and 2) capturing a base with a small force, in which case, you might want to intentionally put in small holes that you can patch after all resistance is cleared